# Forcing to Download A File

Tags: php, file, download

I'm developing a web service. With this service, user's will upload their **.php** files, and service will remove UTF8 BOM characters from php file. And then, There will be a link like this :

`<a href="uploads/as8df7/uploadedfile.php">Download Your File</a>`

But when i click this link, browser browsing to this file. I don't want browse it, i want to download it. So , when user click this link, downloading will start.

Any ideas ?

(P.S. I don't want modify *uploadedfile.php* file, also i read 5 questions about this, but still i have problem.)

Comment: You will need to modify `uploadedfile.php`. No way around it

Comment: But user will download `uploadedfile.php` ?

Comment: in its current form, you will be *executing* the uploaded file, which is a no-no. You need a transport script that sends the right headers and passes through the file's source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're allowing people to upload PHP files on your server, then giving them a link to execute that PHP file. The web server is automatically treating those uploaded PHP files like any other PHP file, i.e. executing it, which opens you up to a massive security hole.

Whatever purpose your web service has, I'd suggest renaming the file on your server when it is uploaded (something 'random' is best, without an extension), then having a PHP script feed it back out with the appropriate headers set when it is requested.

The URL for such a script would look like:

```
http://www.example.com/get_uploaded_file.php?id=jgh3h8gjdj2389
```

It would link the value in `id` with the file on the server, and if you've saved the original filename somewhere (flat file, DB), you can serve it out using its original name, so long as you set the right HTTP headers.

Answer (score 4):

You need to supply this HTTP header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.txt
```

You can usually specify this for entire directories at a time by configuring your web server appropriately.  If you mention which web server you are using, somebody may be able to suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Linking directly to the PHP file may end up executing it. One way is (like somebody above suggested) to rename it. Or, you can have a downloader.php which does below:

```php
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 2000 01:00:00 GMT'); // some date in past
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filepath));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
flush(); // or any other flush function/mechanism you use.
readfile($filepath);
```

and link it something like:
`<a href="./downloader.php?fileid=4ba213">Download</a>`

This method will let you retain the `.php` extension. Also, if the PHP file is big and connection is slow, they progress-bar would be accurate (because you've flushed the content length upfront.